# Command line program to perform CSG / Boolean operations

Tags: command-line, 3d, modeling

I'm looking for a command line program that can perform constructive solid geometry, aka Boolean operations on meshes. I would like to use it like this:

```
intersect a.stl b.stl result.stl
```

[Blender can do this operation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html), but not from the command line.

[MeshLab](http://www.meshlab.net/) can do this from the command line, but unfortunately it resamples the mesh which increases the file size and makes the mesh look blurry. This is not the case with the implementation in Blender.

Comment: Welcome!  Command line from what operating system?

Comment: I'm on windows. If there is a solution for Linux, I'd be interested as well.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, you can run Blender from the command line:

```
blender -b -P intersect.py -- a.stl b.stl result.stl
```

And that's the python script `intersect.py`:

```
import bpy
import sys

index = sys.argv.index("--")
file_a = sys.argv[index + 1]
file_b = sys.argv[index + 2]
file_out = sys.argv[index + 3]

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action = 'SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete()

bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath = file_a)
obj_a = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]

bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath = file_b)
obj_b = bpy.context.selected_objects[0]

bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj_a
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type = 'BOOLEAN')
bpy.context.object.modifiers[0].object = obj_b
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier='Boolean')

bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj_b
bpy.ops.object.delete()

bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj_a
bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath = file_out)
```